# Working with serial without data loss

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi3, pyserial

I'm listening serial port using `pySerial`. Data processed only when I got chunk of data, that I can process. Simple event dispatcher listen for events from readet, then event data handled. Handling may involve IO, Networking and another type of time-consuming OS operations. But who will read data from serial in time of processing last data?

For example

```
    Port stream >> | 1111111111111111 | 222222 | 2222222 | 33333
                   ---------------------------------------------
Programm thread >> | listen port 1 -> | handle | listen2 | .....
```

So data from port which come in time on handling will be lost? like starting of package of `2`?

How to to guarantee, that all data from port will be processed in time?

- Hardware: Raspberry PI 3b
- OS: Raspbian
- Python: v2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of circular buffers and threads in python would be a solution. Another one would be to implement a different protocol so the sender waits for the listener to acknowledge reception before sending new data